# Risk adjusted returns for a portfolio relative to CAPM

Tags: equities, asset-pricing, capm, fama-french

This is very likely a simple question. When following [Lewellen (2015)](https://doi.org/10.1561/104.00000024) (open access [here](https://faculty.tuck.dartmouth.edu/images/uploads/faculty/jonathan-lewellen/ExpectedStockReturns.pdf)), how should I compute alphas for portfolio returns relative to the CAPM and FF3? Do we simply subtract the (beta * lambda) from the excess returns, to get alpha? Or do we subtract (beta * lambda) + constant from the excess returns? I am guessing the former, since the return based on the risk would be (beta * lambda). Just double checking.

**References**

- Lewellen, J. (2015). The cross-section of expected stock returns. Critical Finance Review, 4(1), 1–44. https://doi.org/10.1561/104.00000024

Comment: The text is easier to read if you format the reference the way I did in your last two posts. Consider following that example.

Comment: I agree, thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Julien. Good question. I guess you mean Table 7? Simple form your portfolios to get a time series of portfolio returns. Subtract the risk-free rate to get excess returns. Then simply estimate a single regression of portfolio return on market factor. The intercept of that regression if your CAPM alpha. You do this for each of the ten portfolios to get the ten alphas. To get the FF alphas, you regress your portfolio returns on market factor, SMB and HML. Again, you estimate on regression for each portfolio and report the intercept (and t-statistic).

Comment: Hey Kevin. Thank you for your response. I do indeed mean Table 7. So I assume with the market factor, you mean the beta of (rm - rf),  from a past rolling window. And then I regress the portfolio return (seperately for each decile) on this beta in each time period, and then I get the constant of each time period and then take the average constant across time periods. And this I report as the abnormal outperformance or underperformance for that portfolio when compared to pricing based on its underlying risk factors. Is this correct?

Comment: @JulienMaas It's actually much simpler. You don't need rolling windows at all! For each of then ten portfolios, you run one single (full-sample) time-series regression of their excess returns on the market factor: $r-r_f = \alpha+\beta (r_{m}-r_f)+\varepsilon$. The estimated intercept is the alpha that Lewellen reports. You do this for each of the ten decile portolios and you get the first column in the first panel. What you suggest (ie, run periodic cross-sectional regressions on estimated betas is more like a FM application than portfolio intercepts - related but different).

Comment: I see, haha, I guess I was overthinking it. I also don't see him explicitly stating using a newey west correction for this one, so I assume I can use a regular time series regression then like you said using the excess return of the market directly. And then just take the constant and regular t-stat. I appreciate you taking the time and effort to respond, also on the other posts! I guess here we say that after explaining the part of returns that shift due to correlation (exposure) to the market, the rest is either outperformance or underperformance after considering this risk factor.

Comment: @JulienMaas My pleasure! You asked some really good questions. Sorry that I only noticed them today. You're right that Lewellen doesn't mention Newey-West for table 7 but I'm quite sure he still used it. It's just so common to correct your standard errors. I'd recommend to still implement that correction. Your explanation of the table and the meaning of alpha is spot on. That's exactly the point of table 7. Btw, add an @ at the beginning of a comment on this site to make sure the other user gets a notification and sees your comment. Also, feel free to reach out if you have more questions!